# Variable number of entries, but can't get the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a tool for a spreadsheet. I open a table where I enter strings in each row in the first column.

If I now open my tool, entries are created, which have the creation of the columns from the excel table. So I have a variable number of entries.

A 2nd table is then created in which the columns from table 1 act as headers. If I now enter data into the entries and press "Save", the data should be inserted into the 2nd Excel file as well as in the GUI with the help of a list box.

My problem is that the data that is entered is not inserted into the list box or Excel spreadsheet.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os.path
import openpyxl


class FlexTabApp(): 

    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("FlexTab")
        frame = Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief="sunken")
        frame.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, E, S, W))
        root.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.entry_widgets = []  # initialize entry_widgets

        excel_file_path = r'C:\Users\BZ-eldag\Documents\Python\FlexTab\FlexTab_List.xlsx'

        if os.path.exists(excel_file_path):
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
            ws = wb.active
            
            row_index = 1
            row_values = []
            while True:
                row = ws[row_index]
                if not all([cell.value is None for cell in row]):
                    row_values.append([cell.value for cell in row])
                else:
                    break
                row_index += 1
            
            used_headers = [entry_widget.label.cget("text") for entry_widget in self.entry_widgets if entry_widget.get()]
            self.remove_unused_headers(used_headers)
            wb.close()

            new_excel_file_path = r'C:\Users\BZ-eldag\Documents\Python\FlexTab\FlexTab_Tabelle.xlsx'

            if os.path.exists(new_excel_file_path):
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(new_excel_file_path)
            else:
                wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

            ws = wb.active

            for i, values in enumerate(row_values):
                for j, value in enumerate(values):
                    if value is not None:
                        value = str(value)
                    ws.cell(row=j+1, column=i+1, value=value)

            wb.save(new_excel_file_path)
            wb.close()

            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(new_excel_file_path)
            ws = wb.active

            row_index = 2
            col_index = 1
            max_cols_per_row = 5
            row_offset = 0

            for col in ws.iter_cols():
                if col and col[0].value is not None:
                    label = col[0].value
                    
                    label_widget = Label(frame, text=label)
                    label_widget.grid(row=row_index+row_offset, column=col_index)

                    entry = Entry(frame, width=15)
                    entry.grid(row=row_index+row_offset+1, column=col_index)

                    col_index += 1
                    if col_index > max_cols_per_row:
                        col_index = 1
                        row_offset += 2
                        wb.close()

        else:
            print(f'Die Datei {excel_file_path} existiert nicht.')

        self.data_list = []

        self.data_listbox = Listbox(frame)
        self.data_listbox.grid(row=row_index+row_offset+3, column=1, columnspan=max_cols_per_row*2)

        save_button = Button(frame, text="Speichern", command=self.save_data)
        save_button.grid(row=row_index+row_offset+2, column=1)

    def save_data(self):
        self.data_list.append([entry_widget.get() for entry_widget in self.entry_widgets])
        for entry in self.data_list:
            self.data_listbox.insert(END, entry)

        new_excel_file_path = r'C:\Users\BZ-eldag\Documents\Python\FlexTab\FlexTab_Tabelle.xlsx'
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(new_excel_file_path)
        ws = wb.active
        for i, entry_widget in enumerate(self.entry_widgets):
            if entry_widget.get():
                header = entry_widget.label.cget("text")
                value = entry_widget.get()
                ws.cell(row=1, column=i+1, value=header)
                ws.cell(row=ws.max_row+1, column=i+1, value=value)
        wb.save(new_excel_file_path)
        wb.close()

    def remove_unused_headers(self, used_headers):
        new_excel_file_path = r'C:\Users\BZ-eldag\Documents\Python\FlexTab\FlexTab_Tabelle.xlsx'

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(new_excel_file_path)
        ws = wb.active

        col_index = 1
        while True:
            if ws.cell(row=1, column=col_index).value is None:
                break

            header = str(ws.cell(row=1, column=col_index).value)
            if header not in used_headers:
                ws.delete_cols(col_index)
            else:
                col_index += 1

        wb.save(new_excel_file_path)
        wb.close()
        

root = Tk()
FlexTabApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You forget to store those entry widgets into `self.entry_widgets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you forgot to store the entries (and the matching label) in the self.entry_widget
Below code works for me and stores the values in the excel. However, I had the impression that some of the code is overcomplicating things and can be significantly stripped down.

```
import os.path
from tkinter import *

import openpyxl


# Ausführbare Datei wurde mit "pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole .\main.py" erstellt, damit sich kein CMD-Fenster zum Programm öffnet.
# Wenn einem das egal ist gibt man einfach"pyinstaller --onefile main.py" ein

class FlexTabApp():

    def __init__(self, root):
        # Definiere tkinter Fenster
        root.title("FlexTab")
        frame = Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief="sunken")
        frame.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, E, S, W))
        root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.entry_widgets = []  # initialize entry_widgets
        self.data_list = []
        self.data_listbox = []

        # Pfad zur Excel-Datei, die geöffnet werden soll
        excel_file_path = r'./FlexTab_List.xlsx'

        # Prüfe, ob die Excel-Datei vorhanden ist
        if os.path.exists(excel_file_path):
            # Öffne die Excel-Datei
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
            ws = wb.active

            # Suche nach Zeilen, bis ein leeres Feld kommt
            row_index = 1
            row_values = []
            while True:
                row = ws[row_index]
                if not all([cell.value is None for cell in row]):
                    # Füge die Werte aus der aktuellen Zeile der Liste hinzu
                    row_values.append([cell.value for cell in row])
                else:
                    # Beende die Schleife, wenn ein leeres Feld gefunden wurde
                    break
                row_index += 1

                # Rufe die Funktion zum Entfernen der nicht verwendeten Spaltenüberschriften auf
            used_headers = [entry_widget.label.cget("text") for entry_widget in self.entry_widgets if
                            entry_widget.get()]
            self.remove_unused_headers(used_headers)
            # Schließe die Excel-Datei
            wb.close()

            # Pfad zur Excel-Datei, in der die Werte als Header eingefügt werden sollen
            new_excel_file_path = r'./FlexTab_Tabelle.xlsx'

            # Öffne die neue Excel-Datei oder erstelle sie, wenn sie noch nicht existiert
            if os.path.exists(new_excel_file_path):
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(new_excel_file_path)
            else:
                wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

            # Wähle das aktive Arbeitsblatt aus
            ws = wb.active

            # Füge die Werte aus der Liste als Header ein
            for i, values in enumerate(row_values):
                for j, value in enumerate(values):
                    # Konvertiere den Wert in einen String, wenn er nicht None ist
                    if value is not None:
                        value = str(value)
                    # Füge den Wert in die Zelle ein
                    ws.cell(row=j + 1, column=i + 1, value=value)

            # Speichere die neue Excel-Datei
            wb.save(new_excel_file_path)

            # Schließe die neue Excel-Datei
            wb.close()

            # Öffne die neue Excel-Datei erneut, um die Header-Spalten auszulesen
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(new_excel_file_path)
            ws = wb.active

            # Iteriere durch jede Spalte und erstelle ein Entry-Feld mit der Beschriftung aus dem Spaltennamen
            row_index = 2  # Die zweite Zeile enthält die Header
            col_index = 1
            max_cols_per_row = 5  # Maximal 5 Entry-Felder pro Zeile
            row_offset = 0

            for col in ws.iter_cols():
                if col and col[0].value is not None:
                    label = col[0].value

                    # Erstelle ein Label-Widget mit der Beschriftung
                    label_widget = Label(frame, text=label)
                    label_widget.grid(row=row_index + row_offset, column=col_index)

                    # Erstelle ein Entry-Widget
                    entry_widget = Entry(frame, width=15)
                    entry_widget.grid(row=row_index + row_offset + 1, column=col_index)
                    self.entry_widgets.append((label_widget, entry_widget))

                    col_index += 1
                    if col_index > max_cols_per_row:
                        col_index = 1
                        row_offset += 2  # Erhöhe den Offset um 2, um Platz für das Label-Widget zu schaffen

                        # Schließe die neue Excel-Datei
                        wb.close()

        else:
            print(f'Die Datei {excel_file_path} existiert nicht.')

        # Erstelle flexible GUI

        # Erstelle eine Liste zur Speicherung der eingegebenen Daten
        self.data_list = []

        # Erstelle eine Liste, um die eingegebenen Daten anzuzeigen
        self.data_listbox = Listbox(frame)
        self.data_listbox.grid(row=row_index + row_offset + 3, column=1, columnspan=max_cols_per_row * 2)

        # Erstelle den Button zum Speichern der Daten
        save_button = Button(frame, text="Speichern", command=self.save_data)
        save_button.grid(row=row_index + row_offset + 2, column=1)

    # Erstelle die Funktion zum Speichern der Daten
    def save_data(self):
        # Füge die Einträge in die Liste hinzu
        self.data_list.append([entry_widget[1].get() for entry_widget in self.entry_widgets])
        for entry in self.data_list:
            self.data_listbox.insert(END, entry)

        # Füge die Daten zur zweiten Excel-Tabelle hinzu
        new_excel_file_path = r'./FlexTab_Tabelle.xlsx'
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(new_excel_file_path)
        ws = wb.active
        for i, entry_widget in enumerate(self.entry_widgets):
            if entry_widget[1].get():
                header = entry_widget[0].cget("text")
                value = entry_widget[1].get()
                ws.cell(row=1, column=i + 1, value=header)
                ws.cell(row=ws.max_row + 1, column=i + 1, value=value)
        wb.save(new_excel_file_path)
        wb.close()

    def remove_unused_headers(self, used_headers):
        # Pfad zur neuen Excel-Datei
        new_excel_file_path = r'./FlexTab_Tabelle.xlsx'

        # Öffne die Excel-Datei
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(new_excel_file_path)
        ws = wb.active

        # Iteriere durch jede Spalte und entferne die Spaltenüberschrift, falls sie nicht verwendet wurde
        col_index = 1
        while True:
            # Stoppe die Schleife, wenn das Ende der Zeile erreicht wurde
            if ws.cell(row=1, column=col_index).value is None:
                break

            # Entferne die Spaltenüberschrift, falls sie nicht verwendet wurde
            header = str(ws.cell(row=1, column=col_index).value)
            if header not in used_headers:
                ws.delete_cols(col_index)
            else:
                col_index += 1

        # Speichere die Excel-Datei
        wb.save(new_excel_file_path)

        # Schließe die Excel-Datei
        wb.close()


root = Tk()
FlexTabApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.data_list.append([...])` should be `self.data_list = [...]`.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. You are right, I really programmed a bit chaotically in some places.  I check , how I can optimise my work structure.